# Pass Variable Into A Table Field/Record (SQL/Webmatrix)

Tags: sql, variables, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to run an INSERT query in a cshtml file but I'm having problems passing a variable into a field. The query works if I enter a static number but when I include @0 to pass my variable I get the error:

"A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement."

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4)
            SELECT @0, field2, field3, field4
            FROM table2", myVariable);
```

The field and variable are both int.

Can someone please tell me how to insert my variable ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4)
            SELECT " + myVariable + ", field2, field3, field4
            FROM table2");
```

However, bypassing the standard of always using parameterized queries is a bad idea because it opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

You could instead use:

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field3, field4)
            SELECT * FROM table2");
```

This would return all columns, and then you can choose later which ones to show/hide.  Assuming your table isn't monstruously big, this could work nicely without any performance issues.